# Haskell and Sqlite3 - Convert "SqlValue" to "Integer"

Tags: haskell, sqlite

Suppose I have the following Sqlite statement:

```
res <- quickQuery' conn_1 "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM company WHERE code = ? " [toSql code]
```

I want to convert the result to Integer
and then do something like,

```
if  numRowsReturned == 0
then  something
else somethingElse
```

I tried all the possible ways and now am now fed up with it.

Comment: As discussed on the FB Haskell thread, http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=SqlValue%20-%3E%20&start=0 is the starting point (ConvertResult is what you're looking for).

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell me whether or not there's a way to count the number of tuples returned by the query quickQuery' conn_1 "SELECT * FROM company WHERE code= ? " [toSql code]

Answer (score 3):

`safeFromSql :: Convertible SqlValue a => SqlValue -> ConvertResult a` is what you want, though it might not immediately look like it. Let's assume that `a ~ Integer`. First we check to see that this assumption is admissible by [seeing if there exists an `instance Convertible SqlValue Integer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/convertible-1.0.11.1/docs/Data-Convertible-Base.html#t%3aConvertible). It's not in the `convertible` package, but it does exist and we can see it in [the instance list for `SqlValue`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.3.1.2/docs/Database-HDBC.html#t%3aSqlValue).

So now we know that `safeFromSql :: SqlValue -> ConvertResult Integer` is admissible. Let's see how we could use it.

```
> safeFromSql (SqlInteger 10) :: ConvertResult Integer
Right 10
```

We see that `ConvertResult` is just `type ConvertResult a = Either ConvertError a`—i.e. an Either type. We thus need to handle failure in order to properly use the `ConvertResult`

```
doWithSqlValue :: SqlValue -> IO ()
doWithSqlValue someSqlValue = 
  case safeFromSql someSqlValue of
    Left err  -> print err 
    Right val -> print val
```